# Printing odd and even numbers in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to programming; I want to print odd and even number inside a loop the problem that the if does not work and it will always print else no matter the number you have entered:

```
DECLARE
x NUMBER:=:x;
r NUMBER:=:r;
BEGIN
LOOP
if x/2=0 AND r/2!=0 then
dbms_output.put_line('Even number x='||x);
dbms_output.put_line('Odd number r='||r);
x:= x+2;
r:= r+2;
else
dbms_output.put_line('Odd number x='||x);
dbms_output.put_line('Even number r='||r);
x:=x+2;
r:=r+2;
exit when x>20 and r>20;
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Hi there. It looks like rather than wanting the result of a simple division, you want the "remainder" on doing the division. For that you want the modulo function: `mod(x,2)` rather than `x/2`.

Comment: You should learn that **indentation** can provide a lot to the readibility of your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of x/2=0 you need to use mod(x,2)=0 to check whether it's even number or not. I have separated the condition for x and r. Check out below code:

```
    DECLARE
x NUMBER:=2;
r NUMBER:=3;
BEGIN
LOOP
if mod(x,2)=0 then
dbms_output.put_line('Even number x='||x);
else
dbms_output.put_line('Odd number x='||x);
end if;

if mod(r,2)=0 then
dbms_output.put_line('Even number r='||r);
else
dbms_output.put_line('Odd number r='||r);
end if;
x:= x+2;
r:= r+2;

exit when x>20 and r>20;

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SteveLovell. I didn't check the code properly. My mistake. Thanks again for notifying me..